# call a method when opening a page xhtml [primefaces]

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to call a method without clicking any Boutton but I failed to realized.

I call the method with the traditional way I create a button that has a method called

this is the code of button:

```
 <p:commandButton process="@form" value="ecouter"  action="#{alarmeBean.alarme}" />
```

**but my need is to call the method when opening my page (the methode is alarme )??**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to call method in the backing bean at every HTTP request (including page refreshing) :

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{alarmeBean.alarme}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
```

Otherwise, to call a method once the page is *only* loaded (for 1st time), you should annotate it by "post constructed" in order to invoke it in the construction's bean phase (which shouldn't be `@RequestScoped` to avoid sending requests to the server side, which makes page refreshing and then invokes the method again, which is not desired):

```
@PostConstruct
public void alarme(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: thx 

it is functional but since I have the tag 
<p:poll interval="3" update="dataTable"/> 
which updates a table in my page XHML 
with each refresh it calls the method

Comment: Is the method invoked ? What's the scope of the managed bean ?

Comment: I used **System.out.println ("succed");** to test if the method is invoked but no result

Answer (score 0):

Use preRenderView like Omar said. I mean:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{alarmeBean.alarme}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
```

in order to avoid calling it on each poll refresh check if this is an ajax request from poll or it's a complete Get request like below in `alarme` method.

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
if (fc.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) {
    // ignore this request, we are only interested in GET full page requests
    return;
}
```